# how can i track visits to ALL of the subpages of my website COMBINED TOGETHER?

Tags: google-analytics

Right now I'm using statcounter and Google analytics. They are great. But my counts are currently separated. Ex: website.com = 1000 visits a day, website.com/about = 50 visits a day, website.com/privacy = 10 visits a day, etc..

How can have a combined count of all of my sub-pages? (mainpage + about page + about 100 other sub-pages )

I can of course manually add them all together, but that's time consuming because there are many pages. I tried placing a separate tracking code in a PHP include that sits in each of the sub-pages, but it doesn't seem to be working. It seems to require a single URL to create it, which it then only counts the visits from the one URL, rather than ALL of them. Ex: website.com)

Comment: Google Analytics allows creating reports for your entire website too. You should just create a single analytics account and add the required code to all pages. Then you can see all kinds of data, for both the entire website and separate pages. But also per browser, per country etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm confused about the issue here - On Google Analytics this is in the top "site usage" section of the dashboard and on statcounter it's on the "summary" report (the first one on the list).

Comment: thanks for responding. So here's the issue, does my one-time addition of code ONLY to the main page of the website (website.com), also count visits to OTHER PAGES of the website (website.com/about) ? I would think that the code would have to be placed ON EVERY PAGE of the website to count ALL visits, but i could be wrong. Does this make sense Ewan?

Comment: Yes, you need to place the code on all the pages of the site but use the same profile ID for all of them.

Comment: ok great! so doing that will then give me some form of breakdown between pages? So i can for instance, see that website.com/about is getting 100 visits a day vs website.com/contact is only getting 50 visits a day? yes?

Comment: Yes, that's right

Comment: bonus question: right now i have the same profile ID code in an include on every page, but i also have a second diff ID specifically set up for each page (like dozens). i am assuming that the first code is ignored, because the 2nd is always farther down the page, thus parsed last. yes?

Comment: It's possible for them both to collect data and send it to the appropriate profiles. However, you might find that the second script re-initializes the `_gaq` variable and that will remove the tracking for the first profile. You should remove the second `var _gaq = _gaq || [];` line and also the second function that loads the ga.js script.

Comment: perfect, i tried one, ill check tomorrow if the readings change. thanks!

Comment: works great. thanks again Ewan, i know its a stupid mistake on my part to miss that, but i really appreciate the help.